# $T^2v = \lambda^2v \Rightarrow Tv = |\lambda|v$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I'm not sure if this claim is true or not, and if it is true, I'm trying to give a proof:

For linear transformation $T$ and vector $v$,

$T^2v = \lambda^2v$ implies $Tv = |\lambda|v$

It would be particularly interesting to make no assumptions about the field, but if we need to know the field then we can assume $F=\mathbb{R}$ or $F=\mathbb{C}$.  I'm trying to solve a problem from Axler's *Linear Algebra Done Right* (7.D #10, proving that if $T$ is self-adjoint then its singular values are the absolute values of the eigenvalues) and I'm pretty sure this is a useful or necessary lemma.

My attempt so far: From the hypothesis $(T^2 - \lambda^2)v = 0 = (T-\lambda I)(T+\lambda I)v$.  If $(T+\lambda I)v = 0$ then we're done.  But if not $(T+\lambda I)v = w \ne 0$ and $(T-\lambda I)w = 0$ so that $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $w$.  But from $Tw = \lambda w = T(T+\lambda I)v = \lambda (T+\lambda I)v$ just reduces to a previous assumption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's false.  Let $\{u,v\}$ be a basis for $\mathbb{R}^2$ and define $T$ by $Tu=v$ and $Tv=u$.

Comment: To expand this idea, $u+v$ is an e.vec with e.val 1, and $u-v$ is an e.vec with e.val -1.  $T^2u = u$ but $u$ is not an e.vec of $T$.  Got it, thanks!